# Why does the following sum substitution work?

Tags: summation

$$
=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}
$$$$
=\sum_{i^{\prime}=0}^{n-1} \frac{i^{\prime}\left(i^{\prime}+1\right)}{2}
$$

I see that $i' = n - i$, but shouldn't then the bounds be different?
Like for the lower bound $n - 1$ as you substitute in $1$ for $i$ and vice versa?

Comment: The bounds changed from $1, n$ to $n-1, n-n$.

Comment: Just set $i'=n-i$.

Comment: "*shouldn't the bounds be different?  like for the lower bound n-1...*"  If I wanted to add $a+b+c+d$ I could do so from left to right, starting with $a$, then adding $b$, then adding $c$, etc...  or, and stay with on me on this, I could have added *from right to left!*  So, start with $d$ and then add $c$ and then add $b$ and finally add $a$.  That's all that happened here.  Instead of adding from left to right we just changed to adding from right to left and adjusted the sum and indexing variable to match.

Comment: This question seems fine for me, I don't know why it was downvotes. I demand downvoter to comeback and write its reason for downvote. also I demand downvoter to pay attention to this question and remove their downvote if an edit is made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that by $k=n-i$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}=\sum_{k=n-1}^{0} \frac{k(k+1)}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$